# Contact us form Node Js/express 404 error

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express

I am trying to create an form that allows a person to send me an email. 
However, I am getting a 404 error, shown below.
The form itself is rendering, so what I have in index.js is working.
Do I need some additional code somewhere else or am I missing a few additional pieces of code.
I have nodemailer etc and all the necessary packages installed too.
I am very new to this and I would appreciate any help.
Thank you!

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNnaU.png)

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.post('/contactus', function (req, res) {
      var mailOpts, smtpTrans;
      //Setup Nodemailer transport, I chose gmail. Create an application-specific password to avoid problems.
      smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
          user: "me@gmail.com",
          pass: "xxxxxx"
        }
      });
      //Mail options
      mailOpts = {
        from: req.body.name + req.body.email,
        to: 'yyyyyyyyyy@gmail.com',
        subject: req.body.email + '  --Msg from contactus-form',
        text: "Name: " + req.body.name + "Email: "  + req.body.email + 
              "Contact No:  " + req.body.contactNo + "QUERY: " + req.body.message
      };
      smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
        //Alert on event of message sent succeeds or fail.
        if (error) {
          res.render('contactus',{msg : 'Error occured, message not sent.', err : true});
        }
        else {
          res.render('contactus',{msg : 'Message sent! Thank you.', err : false});
        }
        smtpTrans.close();
      });
});
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

contactus.hbs

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <form action="/contactus" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="30" required="" placeholder="Name:">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="contactNo" size="30" placeholder="Contact No.:">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="email" size="30" required="" placeholder="Email:">
          </p>
          <p><br>
            <textarea type="text" name="message" cols="37" rows="7" size="30" placeholder="Your message please"></textarea>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
          </p><br>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i mean.. the 404 comes first. Express middleware/routes run in the order used.

Answer (score -1):

This handler:

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

Should be moved to just before the 500 error handler.

The reason, it acts as a catch all. Meaning it will always execute if something before it did not route some place first. So it runs and sends the 404 before it has a chance to get to the `contactus` route.

Comment: Thank you so much, that actually makes sense!

Comment: It is customary to accept the answer if it satisfies you needs. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what it means by this? Sorry for this  https://ibb.co/nLLfWc

Comment: Why the downvote? What is the reason? How can I improve the answer?

Comment: @John - You are not using `nodemailer.createTransport()` properly. It appears the `createTransport()` method requires a configuration object as the first parameter rather than a string as you have it. Please check the documentation for that library.

Comment: @ŞükranEken - to reiterate the reasons to downvote: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down - please re-read that carefully before you remove your downvote.

Comment: @ŞükranEken - and finally, StackExchange clearly indicates it is acceptable to ask a new user to accept an answer. So I request you remove you downvote again: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on